# Can't create an instance of an Objective-C class in Swift

Tags: objective-c, swift

I have a class that I have written in Objective-C and I am trying to make an object of it in Swift. I have added the import into the bridging header and can create an object but once I try to call the method init or any other method, I get an error.

This is the class in Objective-C:

```
@interface switchWrapperWrapper: NSObject {
    struct switchWrapper *switchwrapper;
}

- (id)init;

- (void)dealloc;

- (void)findAllInputDevices;
```

BridgingHeader.h

```
#import "switchwrapperwrapper.h"
```

File.swift

```
var temp: switchWrapperWrapper = switchWrapperWrapper();

temp.init() // I get an error "Expected declaration"
```

UPDATE:

I am trying to init an object by using a constructor but have problems calling the constructor from the swift file

```
- (id) init {
    if (self = [super init]) {
        struct switchWrapper switchwrapper;
        switchwrapper.switcher = new Switch();
    } return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You want:

```
temp = switchWrapperWrapper()
```

not:

```
temp.init()
```

You need to call the initializer on the class and assign to the variable.

BTW - the line:

```
var temp: switchWrapperWrapper!
```

simply declares a variable. It does not create an instance. It's really no different than in Objective-C:

```
switchWrapperWrapper *temp;
```

This would then need to be followed at some point by an actual create of an object.

As a side note, class and struct names should start with uppercase letters. Variable and method names start with lowercase.

Comment: I still cannot call the method even after I change to:
var temp: switchWrapperWrapper = switchWrapperWrapper()

Comment: The call to `temp.init()` isn't needed (or valid). You create the instance with `switchWrapperWrapper()`.

Comment: I thing I asked the wrong question 
I am trying to init an object with a constructor but cannot access it from the swift file. (see in update)

Comment: `switchWrapperWrapper()` is calling the `init`. The line `var temp = switchWrapperWrapper()` in Swift is the same as doing `switchWrapperWrapper *temp = [[switchWrapperWrapper alloc] init];` in OC.

Comment: @Paul `switchWrapperWrapper()` is equivalent to `switchWrapperWrapper.init()`, which both allocates and initialized the object. No need for an additional `.init()` call because it _is_ the `.init()` call.